# How can I display image by using image Path in Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, imageview, uri

Firstly,I choose image from gallery ,I upload it to Firebase Storage, and I stock path in Book Node , with other information about Book.

So How can I get image and diplay it in imageView.?

My Activity( what I m doing to get other informations about book):

```
ref = dataBD.getReference("books");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot dataSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            Book valueBook=dataSnap.getValue(Book.class);
            String  idBookDisplay=valueBook.getId_Book();

       if(id_user.equals(idBookDisplay)){

           String titreLivreToDisplay=valueBook.getNom_livre();
           String descLivreToDisplay=valueBook.getDesc_livre();
           String prixLivreToDisplay=valueBook.getPrix_livre();
           String timeToDisplay=valueBook.getDate_creation();

           Book item = new Book();

           item.setNom_livre(titreLivreToDisplay);
           item.setDesc_livre(descLivreToDisplay);
           item.setPrix_livre(prixLivreToDisplay);
           item.setDate_creation(timeToDisplay);

           feedItems.add(item);


       }

        }


        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(AccueilActivity.this,feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

ImageView in Layout File:

```
 <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/book_picture_display"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Node Books:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please store full image path including the firebase storage domain like `gs://<yourapp>.appspot.com/images/<your_image_name>` with this path you will be able to download image from firebase storage.

With the currently visible datasnapshot this is the solution.

Thanks

Comment: I  did it now my image path is like this : `gs://book-...com//images/sport23-03-2017_15:22:54` ,but I have an err : `StorageException has occurred.Object does not exist at location.Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404`

Answer (score 0):

I used to resolve that `FirebaseUI` :

```
storageRef = storageDisplayImg.getReferenceFromUrl(item.getChemin_image()‌​); // return gs://mydreambook-32321.appspot.com/images/test23-03-2017_16:46:55


           Glide.with(convertView.getContext() )
                   .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                   .load(storageRef)
                   .into(profilePic);
            profilePic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```